# (Lightweight) backup strategies for a LAMP application stack?

Tags: php, mysql, backup, lamp, backup-strategies

I'm researching some lightweight tools to backup a LAMP stack. The two most imporatant pieces are the

- php codebase and
- the mysql database.

I can `tar/bz2` the code and a mysqldump and restore it on a new server (if the old one crashes) and this is more or less fine.

Anyway, are there more complete solutions to this?

- e.g. track and re-install additionally installed pear-packages;
- track other packages related to the LAMP stack installed via linux package managers, e.g. APC;
- keep mysql and php configurations alongside backups and being able to restore them automatically ...
- possibly complete server images, which can be restored without the need to reinstall everything ..

I'm curious about hints, tips, experiences, solutions ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP code base should be managed in a version control system such as SVN, Git, etc.  Just creating a tar doesn't give you many capabilities that a proper version control system gives you.

The trouble with mysqldump is that you have to lock the tables you are dumping to ensure a consistent snapshot.  If this takes a long time, other DB operations might timeout while waiting. We use a wonderful [script for snapshotting](http://alestic.com/2009/09/ec2-consistent-snapshot) the running database without excessive locks.  It was designed for the Amazon/EC2 environment but the principals apply to any Linux system with the xfs file system.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great guide for imaging an Ubuntu machine (obviously you can use on other distros):
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35087

In a nutshell (from the article)

```
tar cvpzf backup.tgz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/backup.tgz --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys /
```

To back up the system, then ftp it to another server.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer a few points.  I know it is not a popular package, but I've always revisioned schema with RCS at the server.  It doesn't have to be RCS, but no reason not to dump the CVS/RCS repository with the backup.

For "complete server images," instead of autonomously installing application-requirements (PHP packages &c) we deploy our own `bin/ src/ usr/ var/ lib/` structure as per *each* application which simplifies the backup and system req's perspective.

Hope that helps.

---

I've also seen mysqldumps RCS'd to save only changes.  I'm sure that would be somewhat non-trivial in terms of change management though.